# Is it an obligation to run a node server, in order to execute Angular based applications

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, node.js

(say) My project is using Laravel or simply PHP in the back-end and my front-end is coded using Angular and I am using the angular.js files from the CDN. This should be perfectly fine.

I am confused, when many tutorials and books mention that a node server is required and we start the server and it starts listening to some port. The process of running angular is totally different in this way.

Data bindings or the model in JSON format can be done in many ways. It can be exchanged from php backend and it can also be done through JS running on a node server.

In fact, I could also run an example Angular static application without any server at all. As an example, I put by JSON data, in some variable and then create a $scope. Of course, data will be lost (cannot save data), but it should run. Right!

I would highly appreciate if a someone could clarify, what I am misunderstanding.

Comment: You can use any back end tool to communicate with your Angular app, i.e. Laravel is fine

Answer (score 2):

Angular is front end framework, meaning you need any kind of backend/server to serve home page and load all scripts templates and assets.

It can be nodeJS, or Apache/nginx server running some PHP framework, or you don't even need to use framework, or PHP for that matter, although you would probably need to create some kind of JSON/REST API to have Angular application communicate with your database, but if you just want to communicate with third party services and do something with them on front end, you don't event need any programming language on backend. You can serve index.html from any server and have that load all javascript files and assets

Comment: It's true _you can run an AngularJS based app in any kind of backend/server to serve home page_ but **it is NOT** even mandatory. Since AngularJS is a client side framework you can do whatever you like with your static content (html, css, etc..) without a running server as long as you don't need any back-end processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular on both client and server side, on the client side you simply reference the cdn (or local files) with the script tag (for angular 1, angular 2 requires a little bit more effort), you can also use the framework with node js (server code) for example in a electron app, in this case you would have to install the module with a package manager (such as npm).
 **Notice** that either implementation is respective to the **front-end**.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you can use any backend.
I think the main reason most tutorials on AngularJS application run NodeJS in backend is because both AngularJS and NodeJS are javascript based frameworks so people watching it would understand easily as both front end and back end code looks same *(no new syntax)*.

In fact, that is the reason why I love **MEAN** stack because you can use javascript all over your application event to the database level !!!

**M** - **M**ongoDB (database)

**E** - **E**xpressJS (NodeJS library to handle different routes and HTTP requests and building APIs)

**A** - **A**ngularJS (Javascript based Front end framework)

**N** - **N**odeJS (Javascript runtime which can be executed outside the browser so it can execute your JS code on server).

Answer (score 0):

There is a major difference between Angular 1 and Angular 2. A lot has changed in v2, for instance, the previous directive ng-model is now [(ngModel)], ng-repeat is now *ngFor and so on. Component and Template selectors are in the same class where as Angular dealt more with behaviours. There are many dependencies, specially the System.js and typescript.

Comment: I think with this setup, where it now has many dependencies, we cannot use angular in a straight forward way i.e., simply attach the angular script from CDN or local folder.